# Densly defined $C_{0}$-semigroup extension

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, semigroup-of-operators

Let $(S(t))_{t \geq 0}$ be a $C_{0}$-semigroup on $H$ where $H$ is a Hilbert space. Suppose that $(S(t))_{t \geq 0}$ satisfies the following estimate on a dense subspace on $H$
$$||S(t)x||_H \leq e^{-t}||x||_H.$$
Can this estimate be extended for any $x \in H$?.
Thank you.

Comment: What is your definition of $C_{0}$-semigroup?  Is continuity of each operator baked in?  If so, any continuous operator $L$ on $H$ for which $\|Lx\| \leq C \|x\|$ for $x$ in a dense subspace necessarily has $\|L\| \leq C$.

Comment: Thank you sir for your answer. The problem is the constant C depends on time ( it is an exponential). The question is about the extended semigroup : does it preserve stability?

Comment: Based on what you wrote, it looks like $\|S(t)\| \leq e^{-t}$.